# Form Validation Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format the phone number field based on the country .The logic works fine when the user fill in the details but does not work when the country is changed and filled in again. 
Ex:
Filled in the form for Germany and then without reloading the page if try change county to US and fill  in phone "+" is being added even though format for it is different.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

$('#country').on('change', function() {


      if ( this.value == 'US' || this.value == 'CA')
      {


      $('#C_BusPhone')



    .keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;

        $phone = $(this);

            if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
            if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
                $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
            }
            if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
                $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
            }           
            if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
                $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
            }
        }


        return (key == 8 || 
                key == 9 ||
                key == 46 ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105)); 
    })

    .bind('focus click', function () {
        $phone = $(this);

        if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
            $phone.val('(');
        }
        else {
            var val = $phone.val();
            $phone.val('').val(val); 
        }
    })

    .blur(function () {
        $phone = $(this);

        if ($phone.val() === '(') {
            $phone.val('');
        }
    });

      }
      else
      {
        $('#C_BusPhone')

    .keydown(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val().indexOf("+") === -1) {
      $(this).val("+" + $this.val());
    }
      })

}  

    });  
    });
```

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of a sample code ? it would make debugging way faster

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ranred/dap3L426/

Comment: Does it have to do the formatting as you type?  It would probably be easier to reformat the number onchange. Create a formatter method for each country and attach the correct one/detach the previous one when the country changes.

You should probably store the raw number as a custom data attribute on the element.

Also look at this for actual validation: http://html5pattern.com/Phones

Comment: Actually its not about validation but pre fixing the required format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the cause for your error, but this line needs to get corrected from

```
  $(this).val("+" + $this.val());
```

to this

```
$(this).val("+" + $(this).val());
```

It was a fast catch, just use your browser javascript console for debugging.

See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dap3L426/23/). You might want to add the starting parenthesis to your international prefix as well.